# C# equivalent of Java's timer.scheduleAtFixedRate

Tags: c#, timer

I need a method to run accurately every 5 minutes. I can't use Timer because I noticed it will slowly become out of sync (i.e. it will eventually run at 00:01, 00:06, 00:11, 00:16, and so on).

Although it needs to be accurate, I don't need it to be too precise. Every 5 minutes +/- 1 second will be okay, just as long as after days of running, it will still tick accurately on the 5 minute marks.

What I have thought of so far is creating a Timer with an Interval of 1 second that constantly checks DateTime.Now to see if the next 5 minute mark is passed. I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution or something in the C# libraries that I have missed.

**Edit:** I have the following template now, which is working to my requirements.

```
public class ThreadTest
{
    private Thread thread;
    private long nextExecutionTime;
    private long interval;

    public void StartThread(long intervalInMillis)
    {
        interval = intervalInMillis * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        nextExecutionTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        thread = new Thread(Run);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Ticks >= nextExecutionTime)
            {
                nextExecutionTime += interval;
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you really tried to use System.Threading.Timer? It starts a new thread every specified interval and I never got it out of sync for more than a second.

Comment: The only problem with Timer is that when your worker thread hangs or runs for too long, it will start new and new threads and at some time your application will consume too much resources. In some situation such behavior is inappropriate - then you can implement your own periodic runner. Otherwise use Timer

Comment: I just tried System.Threading.Timer with 1 second intervals and it had gained 230 ms in 4 minutes

Comment: So do you need guaranteed 1s + (5 *runId) min interval between first and runId'th run? In this case Timer really wouldn't guarantee it. It guarantees interval between consecutive runs. So I can't recomment anything better that creating your own class with such functionality (it shouldn't be hard)

Comment: Yes, I think I will have to. I looked through the Java source code, it uses an executionTime variable, and runs a thread that repeatedly checks the current time against the executionTime. When the executionTime is reached, executionTime+=Interval. I will copy this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not happy with Timer?

then **you can try to make your thread sleep for 5 mintues, instead of using Timer**

have a look this, hope it helps

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Worker
{
    // This method will be called when the thread is started.
    public void DoWork()
    {
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            Task.Factory.Start(() => 
               {
                    // do you task async
               })
            Thread.Sleep(300000);
        }
    }

    public void DoWork2()
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            watch.Start();
            Task.Factory.Start(() => 
               {
                    // do you task async
               })

            while(watch.Elapsed.ElapsedMilliseconds < 300000);
            watch.Stop();
            watch.Reset();
        }
    }

    public void RequestStop()
    {
        _shouldStop = true;
    }

    private volatile bool _shouldStop;
}

public class WorkerThreadExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create the thread object. This does not start the thread.
        Worker workerObject = new Worker();
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(workerObject.DoWork);

        // Start the worker thread.
        workerThread.Start();

        // Loop until worker thread activates.
        while (!workerThread.IsAlive);

        while (true)
        {
            //do something to make it break
        }

        // Request that the worker thread stop itself:
        workerObject.RequestStop();
        workerThread.Join();
    }
}
```

or you can try this:

Comment: That would run every 5 minutes + however long it takes to perform the tasks. If my tasks take 30 seconds to run, it would run every 5 minutes and 30 seconds.

Comment: Sure. I guess it is quite easy to figure out how the task actually took((DateTime.Now - someTimeBefore).TotalSeconds), unless it will take more than 5 minutes. If you do not get something better than Timer, then this is probably better than 'creating a Timer with an Interval of 1 second that constantly checks DateTime.Now to see if the next 5 minute mark is passed'

Comment: By the way, if you ever want to count time, try out Stopwatch, it should have better accuracy than DateTime

Comment: That's the approach I went for in the end

Comment: Hey~~, I forget C# can do async function call! Check out the edited answer, we do not need to do a subtraction. Also, there is another version of DoWork, which use Stopwatch, people said it is more accurate than DateTime

Comment: I tested that, and it still slowly becomes out of sync because there is the Sleep, and also creating the new task, which takes additional time. I have a solution that works now though.

Comment: kk, cool, I never noticed that keep a schedule task running on time can be really tricky.

Comment: Also with DoWork2, watch.Start(); should be before Task.Start(), so that it takes account of the time spent on creating task